# Сравнение нескольких столбцов google таблицы и вычисление разницы между ними

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть такая [таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SWvxQoRKex9wHa4iobZykeG65wE-DdRPy8aBcyXkhTc/edit?usp=sharing).

Столбцы содержат наименования и соответствующие им значения. Я отметил цветами совпадающие имена в столбцах `А` и `D`.

Какую использовать формулу, чтобы она сама искала совпадающие имена в столбцах `А` и `D` и при нахождении подсчитывала разницы между значениями, соответствующими этим столбцам, например как у меня сделано вручную в столбце - `G`?

> "В ячейке А2 совпадение с ячейкой D3 и найдена разница между значениями эти ячеек и вписана в G2"

Comment: Через Google Apps Script можно что угодно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать query 
по линку можно найти образец доки с нужной формулой
http://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-total-row/

Comment: Дайте более  развёрнутый ответ, одной ссылки для него недостаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, в каком виде требуется выводить данные. Предполагаю, что, раз требуется найти совпадения, то можно ориентироваться на один из блоков. Пусть это будет первый блок: в `A1:A8` записаны условные имена, в `B1:B8` записаны значения. Собственно, ищем совпадения имен из столбца `A` с именами из столбца `D1:D10` (численные значения к которым записаны рядом -- в `E1:E10`).

Ориентируясь на имена из первого блока, будем записывать результаты в столбец `F1:F8` (такого же размера). В ячейку `F1` запишем значение, соответствующее указанному в `A1` имени из второго блока `D1:E10`. Так и пишем:

`=VLOOKUP(A1;D$1:E$10;2;FALSE) (VLOOKUP(интересуемое_имя; диапазон поиска, в первом столбце которого нужно имя искать, причем знаки доллара у цифр означают, что первая и последняя строки диапазона фиксированы точно; номер столбца в диапазоне, в котором хранятся интересуемые значения; на вопрос, отсортированы ли наши имена, отвечаем FALSE) )`

После чего можно данную формулу в ячейке `F1` маркером автозаполнения растянуть вниз на весь диапазон `F1:F8`. В некоторых ячейках отобразится "НЕТ ДАННЫХ" (N/A). Что означает, что соответствующего имени не нашлось во втором блоке.

Теперь запишем в соседний столбец справа `(G1:G8)` значения из `F1:F8`, исключая N/A. Есть специальная функция для этого, проверяющая, является ли значение в ячейке N/A: `IFNA(ячейка)`. Если записать в `G1` формулу: `=IFNA(F1)`, то будет отображено `TRUE`, если `F1=#N/A`. А нам нужно наоборот, и нужны не `TRUE/FALSE`, а сами значения из столбца `F1:F8`. Воспользуемся конструкцией `IF`:

В `G1` пишем: `=IF(ISNA(F1);"[пусто]";F1)`. В случае, если `ISNA(F1)=TRUE`, ячейка `G1` будет пустой. Если `FALSE`, то в ячейку `G1` попадет значение из `F1`. Воспользовавшись автозаполнением вниз с помощью маркера, заполним этими формулами весь диапазон `G1:G8`. Получим столбец, в котором есть ячейки с числами и ячейки пустые, с которыми Вы уже можете как хотите работать (например, воспользоваться `FILTER,...`). В данном случае Вас интересует разница значений, ее и посчитаем, но об этом в следующем абзаце.

Чтобы не использовать лишний столбец, одну функцию можно запихнуть в другую, и тогда столбец `G1:G8` не понадобится, все значения с пропусками окажутся в `F1:F8`, если написать следующую комбинацию формул в `F1`:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1;D$1:E$10;2;FALSE));"";VLOOKUP(A1;D$1:E$10;2;FALSE)-B1)`

Обращаю внимание, что третий аргумент у функции `IF -- это VLOOKUP(..)-B1`, то есть будет записано не просто найденное значение, а его разность с тем, что записано в `B1`.

Маркером автозаполнения "протянем" формулу вниз до `F8`. Готово.